# string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

i am having problem with my retrieving of date after the date fall after 12. for example : if i click from the calander extender: 2/7/2013 to 19/july/2013 , is will throw it me with this error : The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

this is my code.

```
    var format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    DateTime one = DateTime.ParseExact(startdate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime two = DateTime.ParseExact(enddate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);



    if (two >= one)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=""catalog="";Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name,CLass, NRIC, StallNo, AmountSpent ,TimeDate=convert(nvarchar,timedate,103)  FROM StudentTransactions WHERE TimeDate BETWEEN '" + one + "' AND '" + two + "'", conn);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = reader;
        GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
        GridView1.Visible = true;
        GridView1.DataBind(); 
        conn.Close();
   }
```

Comment: Have you looked at `ParseExact`?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038.aspx

Comment: You ought to use parameters rather than forcing `one` and `two` to be arbitrarily converted back into strings in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select CONVERT(varchar,<datecol>,103)      ---  and will return as dd/mm/yyyy

where convert(date,<datecol>) between '' and ''
```

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(varchar,<TimeDate>,103) * FROM StudentTransactions WHERE convert(date,<TimeDate>) BETWEEN '" + one + "' AND '" + two + "'", conn) i got this error : Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: remove the <>      <datecol> should be your column name ...

select convert(varchar,timedate,103)

Comment: it works well. but may i know is there anyways to change the format of dd/mm/yyyy that i get to MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: why when i choose 13/7/2013 onward its will say : The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Comment: try convert(nvarchar,timedate,103) that should fix it.

Comment: when i choose from the 2/7/2013 to 19/7/2013 , it gave me this error : The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.                                     this is how i do it :                                              var format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        DateTime one = DateTime.ParseExact(startdate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime two = DateTime.ParseExact(enddate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alter the format of a column of a `GridView` from CodeBehind Add a `RowDataBound` to your grid view.

Then in the `GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)` method, you'll be able to access e which will provide you with access to the individual cells of that row where you can specify a format.

[Reference](http://forums.asp.net/p/1589807/4025153.aspx)

[Reference2](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/how-to-set-date-format-in-gridview.html)

Comment: @PorWeiting Check reference2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure first that the date part of your `TimeDate` column is in your desired format, i.e., "dd/mm/yyyy".

```
var format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
DateTime one = DateTime.ParseExact(startdate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime two = DateTime.ParseExact(enddate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

EDIT:
To format the output, you can do ff:
Assuming you have a Boundfield on your TimeDate on your GridView1:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="TimeDate" HeaderText="TimeDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
```

You can also use `DataFormatString="{0:d}"` to output the date in the short date format of your current culture.

Comment: the data print out is still in this formate. which is mm/dd/yyyy with the time :7/3/2013 12:00:00 AM i would like to remove the time and change the format to dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: Oh... so you're trying to format the output.. I misunderstood the question.. Will update my answer.

Comment: Please see my edit... and if it's not working, please provide further info. of your code.

Comment: it still not working. the date format is in MM/dd/yyyy which result in when i chose a date from a calander extender from 12 july onwards it kept me with this error : The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Comment: i read my date from a date picker from another aspx page and pass the date via session and this is my code which how i retrive it:  string startdate = (string)(Session["startdate"]);                 my aspx page from gridview reads the data from my sql statement above which i have stated.

Comment: Can you show the code on how are you saving the TimeDate on your StudentTransactions? It seems you have a conflict between your date format, dd/MM and MM/dd.

Comment: ("SELECT * FROM StudentTransactions WHERE TimeDate BETWEEN '" + one + "' AND '" + two + "'", conn)

Comment: //getting data
        string startdate = (string)(Session["startdate"]);
        string enddate = (string)(Session["enddate"]);
        DateTime one = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate); 
        String ConvertDate = one.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        DateTime two = Convert.ToDateTime(enddate);
        String ConvertDate1 = two.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Comment: Hi, why don't you just set the format of the CalendarExtender to dd/MM/yyyy? I believe you can set it to Format="dd/MM/yyyy".

Comment: i already formated . but i think sql database default is MM/dd/yyyy that why when i choose 13/7/2013 onward its will say : The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.