# Parsing leap year day without year always fails in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to parse birthdays in the format of `d/M` without any year specified.

Using `DateTime.TryParseExact(birthday, "d/M", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime birthdayDate)` works most of the time, except when the birthday is at leap year day (aka `29/2`), and the parsing never succeeds because it is default to current year. Using `DatTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault` does not work either since [it defaults to year = 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimestyles), which is not a leap year.

How do I do the parsing so it does not involve a hack (I don't want to parse it manually or manually add an arbitrary year to parse it as a full date either, they are all ugly and potentially fragile) and still work across all possible dates, including leap day? [Existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561240/string-is-not-supported-in-calendar-system-globalization-gregoriancalendar) does not help at all since nobody bothers to check if they work for leap day at all. I tried all of them and none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A day and a month does not make a date - therefore they can't be parsed as a `DateTime` value without assuming a year.  The .NET Framework assumes a year that is either the current year or year 1 - exactly because 2/29 is valid only on leap years - and this is a very reasonable assumption.

The .Net framework does not provide a built in way to store Day/Month values, but [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) does - Take a look at [`AnnualDate`](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/api/NodaTime.AnnualDate.html) - It stores a day and a month but no year.

However, it doesn't have `Parse` or `TryParse` methods - so for that you still need to manually manipulate the input string and add a year (that is a leap year like 2016) in order to use the `DateTime`'s `TryParseExact` method.

**Update**

As Matt Johnson wrote in his comment, Noda Time does provide a way for parsing text as an `AnnualDate`, using the [`AnnualDatePattern`](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/api/NodaTime.Text.AnnualDatePattern.html) class.
The documentation has a page called [Patterns for AnnualDate values](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/userguide/annualdate-patterns) that lists the supported patterns.

Comment: Noda Time does have parsing for `AnnualDate`.  It's handled by the [`AnnualDatePattern`](https://nodatime.org/api/NodaTime.Text.AnnualDatePattern.html) class.  See [Text Handling](https://nodatime.org/userguide/text) and [Patterns for AnnualDate values](https://nodatime.org/userguide/annualdate-patterns) in the user guide.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for the comment and links. I've edited them into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This question lacks the appropriate details, however

If you just want to parse a **birth date and month** including leap year dates, then just added a leap year to the end of the date.

I am not sure what you expect to do here, however you could try this

```
birthday = $"{birthday}/2016"; // leap year

DateTime.TryParseExact(birthday, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime birthdayDate);
```

**Update**

> my question is how to not make TryParseExact assume the year
>   automatically by manually overriding it in some way

To be technical here, no you have to specify the leap year in the string **if you are parsing a leap year month and day exclusively** as in your example

There is a lot of checks and balances the `TryParseExact` method does, however here are the important bits.

In short, it uses the current year or year 1, and there is no way to tell it to choose a leap year specifically

```
private static bool CheckDefaultDateTime(ref DateTimeResult result, ref Calendar cal, DateTimeStyles styles)
{
  if ((result.flags & ParseFlags.CaptureOffset) != (ParseFlags) 0 && (result.Month != -1 || result.Day != -1) && ((result.Year == -1 || (result.flags & ParseFlags.YearDefault) != (ParseFlags) 0) && (result.flags & ParseFlags.TimeZoneUsed) != (ParseFlags) 0))
  {
    result.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind.Format, "Format_MissingIncompleteDate", (object) null);
    return false;
  }
  if (result.Year == -1 || result.Month == -1 || result.Day == -1)
  {
    DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTimeParse.GetDateTimeNow(ref result, ref styles);
    if (result.Month == -1 && result.Day == -1)
    {
      if (result.Year == -1)
      {
        if ((styles & DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault) != DateTimeStyles.None)
        {
          cal = GregorianCalendar.GetDefaultInstance();
          result.Year = result.Month = result.Day = 1;
        }
        else
        {
          result.Year = cal.GetYear(dateTimeNow);
          result.Month = cal.GetMonth(dateTimeNow);
          result.Day = cal.GetDayOfMonth(dateTimeNow);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        result.Month = 1;
        result.Day = 1;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (result.Year == -1)
        result.Year = cal.GetYear(dateTimeNow);
      if (result.Month == -1)
        result.Month = 1;
      if (result.Day == -1)
        result.Day = 1;
    }
  }
  if (result.Hour == -1)
    result.Hour = 0;
  if (result.Minute == -1)
    result.Minute = 0;
  if (result.Second == -1)
    result.Second = 0;
  if (result.era == -1)
    result.era = 0;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware it could be done like this. However string mangling is *fragile*, and if it's used this way it completely nullifies the point of using `DateTime.ParseExact` (that is, to not mangle strings yourself), which means I'd be better just parse the components myself.

Comment: @user2988819 sure you could parse it your self, and create a datetime out of it, however in the end you are going to have to make the year a leap year for those special cases

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm currently storing the birthday with a dummy leap year anyway. However there are no ways to supply a default year when doing `DateTime.ParseExact`, which is really a bummer, especially when there is already a `DateTimeStyles` that sets the default year to something other than the current year.

Comment: Hi. By not including a year, TryParseExact assumes you mean the current year (2018) which is not a leap year. You can see this by looking at birthdayDate after the event. If you are just checking the "d/M" value and not interested in the actual date produced, then just include the fixed leap year as part of the expression, i.e. DateTime.TryParseExact( birthday + "/2016", "d/M/yyyy", ... .

Comment: @Swanny I *am* aware of that, thank you. Hence my question is how to not make `TryParseExact` assume the year automatically by manually overriding it in some way.

Comment: @user2988819  would you believe me if i said you cant?

Comment: @TheGeneral Yes, I can accept that. I'd really appreciate if the comments have done this at first instead of going through entire lectures why the year is needed though, it's completely unneeded and didn't even answer anything.

Comment: So specifying the year is not "manually overriding" it? Perhaps you could give us a list of inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: @Swanny The entire comment thread in the question was about "you need to specify the year *in the user input*", which is an entirely different thing, uncalled for and utterly wrong. I already elaborated on the reasons. The question is "how can I specify the year *myself*" and is it possible do this without doing string mangling. Like, best practice. I'm not even sure how you people managed to derail the entire question in the first place.

Comment: Your question does not make sense, that's why you've got so many downvotes and repeated comments. A day and a month does not make a date - therefor they can't be parsed as a DateTime value without assuming a year.  The .Net framework assumes a year that is either the current year or year 1 - exactly because 2/29 is valid only on leap years - and this is a very reasonable assumption. The .Net framework does not provide a built in way to store Day/Month values, but Noda Time does - Take a look at [AnnualDate](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/api/NodaTime.AnnualDate.html).

Comment: @ZoharPeled This is not a comment, this is an answer. You can post that as an answer then I'll accept it. But then I can't believe how it takes so many comments just to get out something that's actually useful like your comment does. I thought SO was a place to learn best practices.

Comment: @ZoharPeled elequently stated, answer it up, I'll upvote

Comment: @ZoharPeled - the question made perfect sense, and should not have been downvoted - even if the solution is not possible with the techniques used by the asker (parsing to a `DateTime`, etc), it's still a reasonable question, is clear and understandable, and shows effort.  I have seen a LOT worse questions than this one.

Comment: @MattJohnson it make sense now; that wasn't the case originally... If it was, there wouldn't be all these comments (that are now gone) on the question.

Comment: @MattJohnson The accepted answer is what nearly all the comments where saying in the first place, and is what I stated in my comment. Rather than clarifying OP rudely double downed and stated several times they cannot do that, also claimed everyone else didn't know what they where talking about and where wrong. Now after finally getting what everyone was trying to tell them, they changed their mind and is still pretending that they didn't derail their own question. Such behavior not something we should be wanting new users to act on this site. If anything it wasn't downvoted enough.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek i actually agree with those sentiments, and it was only after and hour or so did the message finally become clear.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for clarifying.